# facebook open graph user content

Tags: arrays, facebook

Is it possible for the og content to be user based so as they share there page from my website it shows there description and there picture? I have tried

```
 <meta property="og:title"       content="<?php echo ['postTitle']; ?>" />
```

for the title but it just says array on the share.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

You could theoretically get the Facebook scraper to re-scrape the URL to use the new title from then on - but that won’t work in practice, for several reasons:

- Facebook “freezes” the title after the object has received a certain amount of likes/shares, you won’t be able to change it any more after that.
- Users who shared the link earlier, and then would happen to use the “refresh share attachment” option in the UI, would then have it show the *current* title in their post, and not the one they shared this originally with.
- Triggering re-scrapes is limited, you can not do that all the time.

---

If you want to share with individual properties, then you will need an individual URL for each combination. That will of course split the likes/shares across those different URLs. So you gotta decide which is more important to you.

Comment: Thanks CBroe Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier.

Comment: Thanks CBroe Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. I find it hard to explain myself sometimes sorry. it would be individual URL's, since i posted this i have worked the part about the content. So the problem i have is that someone creates a form on my site(they make a video) the video is embed from a youtube link onto my site they then share it. I want the og image to be the thumbnail of the you tube video for each form created.